# getting relational results from three tables into one nested array

Tags: php

i have googled for solution to my problem but nun helped me.
here i have three tables `items`, `feeds` and `images`. each item has one feed and one or more images.
 i have 3 functions. one is  to return records from items table the second one receives feeds_id (foreign key in items table) then return records from feeds table. the third function is to return all images related to items_id.

those functions are :

 * To get all items in database:

```
 function get_items(){
  return  $query = Database::getInstance('db')
        ->table('items')
        ->columns(
            'id',
            'items.rowid',
            'items.feed_id as feed_id',
            'title' )
        ->findAll();
}
```

* To get feed data from feeds table :

```
function get_feeds($id){
   return  $query = Database::getInstance('db')
        ->table('feeds')
        ->eq('id',$id)
         ->findAll();
}
```

* To get image data from images table :

```
function get_images($id){
   return  $query = Database::getInstance('db')
        ->table('images')
        ->columns('items_id','src as image_url',
            'title as image_title',
            'alt')
        ->eq('items_id',$id)
        ->findAll();
   }
```

Then i have the following code to call those function and display the result in jsonformat:

```
  $response['items'] = array();
  $response['feeds'] = array();
  $response['images'] = array();   

  foreach ($items = get_items() as $item) {

      $response['items'][] = array(
            'id' => (int)$item['rowid'],
            'feed_id' => (int)$item['feed_id'],
            'title' => $item['title'],
       );

      foreach ($feeds = get_feeds((int)$item['feed_id']) as $feed) {

         $response['feeds'][] = array(
            'title' => $feed['title'],
            'logo_url' => $feed['logo_url'],
            'site_url' => $feed['site_url'],
          );
        }

       foreach ($images = get_images($item['id']) as $image) {

         $response['images'][] = array(
            'id' => $image['items_id'],
            'url' => $image['image_url'],
            'thumb' =>  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . /myServer/images/thumbs/'. 'thumb_'.basename($image['image_url']),
             'title' => $image['image_title'],
             'alt' => $image['alt']
                );
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

so, my expectation is to get json output like:

```
"items": [
        {
            "id": ,
            "feed_id": 
            "title":
            "feeds": [
                      {
                       "title": ,
                       "logo_url": ,
                       "site_url": "
                      }
                    ]
             "images": [
                         {
                          "id": ,
                          "url": ",
                          "thumb": 
                          "title": "",
                          "alt": ""
                         },
                         {
                          ....
                          }
                        ] 
        }]
```

i mean each item array should include nested arrays of its related data coming from    get_feeds and get_images functions.
   instead of that, i get response like :

```
//here i select two items from my db
    "items": [
                { //first_item
                    "id": ,
                    "feed_id": 
                    "title":
                 },
                 { //second_item
                    "id": ,
                    "feed_id": 
                    "title":
                 }
              ],
       "feeds": [
                   { // feed data for first item
                     "title": ,
                      "logo_url": ,
                      "site_url": "
                   },
                   { // feed data for second item
                     "title": ,
                      "logo_url": ,
                      "site_url": "
                   }
               ],
                     "images": [
                                 { // image data for first item
                                  "id": ,
                                  "url": ",
                                  "thumb": 
                                  "title": "",
                                  "alt": ""
                                 },
                                 { // other images data 
                                  ....
                                  }
                                ] 
                }]
```

as you see i am getting output without keeping relation between items, feeds and images, all of them are shown independently.

my queries are fine but i am suspecting error in my `foreach` statements.

i could fix this issue by joining those tree tables in one query, but i don't want to do that because i need to do validation and other operations to output comes from each table.
i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. it is very easy :)

it is just like:

```
 $response['items'][] = array(
            'id' => (int)$item['rowid'],
            'feed_id' => (int)$item['feed_id'],
            'title' => $item['title'],
            'feeds' => array(
             )
          'images' => array(
          )
   );﻿
```